# How to select table in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

```
for($i=0; $i < count($cameras_info); $i++){
    $this->db->select('Image');
    $this->db->from('cameras');
    $this->db->where('id', $cameras_info[$i]->camera_id);
    $cameras_info[$i]->Image = isset($this->db->get()->row()->Image) ? $this->db->get()->row()->Image : NULL;
}
```

When i trying to execute this code i receive this error:

> Error Number: 1096
>  No tables used
>  SELECT *
>  Line Number:
>   167

How to solve this problem?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems in this line:

```
$cameras_info[$i]->Image = isset($this->db->get()->row()->Image) ? $this->db->get()->row()->Image : NULL;
```

`$this->db->get()` executes the query and reset values passed in active record class so when it called after question mark it does not get any values and raises the error. So replace this line with the following:

```
$result = $this->db->get()->row()->Image;
$cameras_info[$i]->Image = isset($result->row()->Image) ? $result->row()->Image : NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

***Assuming you code is correct***

I tried to restructure it as i see fit to your code

```
for($i=0; $i < count($cameras_info); $i++){
    $this->db->select('Image');
    $this->db->from('cameras');
    $this->db->where('id', $cameras_info[$i]->camera_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $cameras_info[$i]->Image = isset($query->row()->Image) ? $query->row()->Image : NULL;
}
```